# How do i delay a layout for 1 second then show another layout in Android

Tags: android

something like  this ...

```
setContentView(R.layout.page1);
Thread.sleep(1000);
setContentView(R.layout.page2);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a CountDownTimer, see
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
Import android.os.CountDownTimer;


setContentView(R.layout.page1);
new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {

   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
   }

   public void onFinish() {
       setContentView(R.layout.page2);
   }

}.start();
```

Comment: thank you very much your code worked. just needed to import android.os.CountDownTimer and type CountdownTimer as CountDownTimer, with capital D.

Comment: Excellent. Got to love that the typo came from copy pasting from the documentation (they didn't use a capital D :)).

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
 SystemClock.sleep(100); //ms
```

Comment: And let the GUI freeze? **NEVER USE SystemClock.sleep** inside a GUI.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `postDelayed(new Runnable(), 1000);` add the action you want to do in the runnable.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way should be:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 2s
  }
}, 2000);
```

This question has already answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166354/6248208)