# Schedule a call to a method?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call a method after a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay)

When a user clicks a button, I want to doThis(myVar1);. 1 second later I want to doThis(myVar2);. How can I schedule that 2nd call?

Comment: with a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a handler and do a `postDelayed()` on a runnable.  Check the [documentation for Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        doThis(myVar2);.
    }
};
...
...
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Comment: Original post doesn't say anything about Android.

Comment: It had the `Android` tag when it was posted.. Edited later.. see the edit history,,,

Comment: @mergeconflict, Now it does again.

Answer (score 2):

try this way using Thread:

```
 btnbtnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mthreadRunning==false)
        {
            doThis(myVar1);
            mthreadRunning=true;
            dojobThread();
        }
    }
});

 public void dojobThread(){
        Thread th=new Thread(){
         @Override
         public void run(){
          try
          {
           while(mthreadRunning)
           {
           Thread.sleep(100L);
           mthreadRunning=false;
           doThis(myVar2);//call doThis(myVar2); here after 1 second delay

           }
          }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
          }
         }
        };
        th.start();
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

In a desktop GUI app, I would use `javax.swing.Timer` from the Swing API. Perhaps the Android API has something similar? Of course, the Thread example above by imran khan is essentially the same thing.