# Checkbox list view troubles

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

I have a list view that is populated with check boxes. The text on each box is set with the `ListAdapter`. When everything loads up I need a few of the check boxes to be checked by default and some of them to not be checked. I am able to call `setChecked` on the check boxes but it is not working. I believe this is because in the `onCreate()` the view is not visible yet. So I moved it to `onResume()` and `onCreate()` and so far it still does not work. It seems that they are still not yet loaded and on the screen yet.

```
private void markAllTags()//this will put a check mark on the ones that are already a tag of that question
{
    String tags[] = mUserDb.fetchTagById(mQid);//These are the tags that are already associated with this question
    for(int i = 0; i < this.getListAdapter().getCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = this.getListAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        //Log.w("NME", "I = " + this.getListAdapter().getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.checkBox1));
        if(v != null)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            String cbTags = "" + cb.getText();
            for(int j = 0; j < tags.length; j++)
            {
                //Log.w("NME", "cbTag = " + cbTags + " tags[j] = " + tags[j]);
                if(cbTags.equals(tags[j]))
                {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is currently being called from onStart.

If I use `listview.getchildAt()` I receive a null value.

EDIT: There is no crash so nothing really coming up in logcat. So the problem is that when the final if statement is met it doesn't mark it as checked.

EDIT 2: So I have tried a few more things. I linked the function above to a button and it still did not work. When I changed the line where `View v` is set. To this `View v = mListView.getChildAt(i);` It worked when I pressed the button. However it still does not work when the activity starts. The problem is now that v is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem there may be a better way and I would love to hear it if there is. I used something I found in an answer to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay) When I call `markAllTags()` inside `onStart()` I have surrounded it with this.

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          markAllTags();
      }
    }, 100);
```

also now my `markAllTags()` function looks like this:

```
private void markAllTags()//this will put a check mark on the ones that are already a tag of that question
{
    String tags[] = mUserDb.fetchTagById(mQid);//These are the tags that are already associated with this question
    for(int i = 0; i < this.getListAdapter().getCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = mListView.getChildAt(i);
        //View v = this.getListAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        //Log.w("NME", "I = " + this.getListAdapter().getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.checkBox1));
        Log.w("NME", "checking to see if V != null");
        if(v != null)
        {
            Log.w("NME", "V != null");
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            String cbTags = "" + cb.getText();
            for(int j = 0; j < tags.length; j++)
            {
                //Log.w("NME", "cbTag = " + cbTags + " tags[j] = " + tags[j]);
                if(cbTags.equals(tags[j]))
                {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                }
            }//end for
        }//end if null

    }//end for
}//end
```

As mentioned in my last edit I changed where I set `View v` other than that it should be about the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this problem by adding an else part to your code as below

```
if(cbTags.equals(tags[j]))
{
cb.setChecked(true);
}else{
cb.setChecked(false);
}
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this did not do the trick. I edited my question to hopefully make my problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the way you'd normally use a ListView.  Generally, you just set the adapter in onCreate, and the initial list of values.  Then in Adapter.getView you would set the value of the checkbox to whatever the view should be.  Calling adapter.getView like that is a bad idea-  that function is used by the list view to create and initialize the views currently on screen, you could cause problems.

Comment: Ok I believe I understand. How should I go about checking certain check boxes and leaving some unchecked?

Comment: When getView is called for a given row, figure out whether you want the checkboxes in that row to be checked or not.  If you do, call setChecked(true).  If not, call setChecked(false).  Make sure to call it in both cases, listviews reuse views for newly scrolled in rows so the checkbox may already be set checked and you'll need to explicitly uncheck it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that didn't quite solve my problem but it got me thinking and I found a solution. I think this will also help me avoid a future bug. My solution might not be the best solution but it will get me by for now. I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question though.