# How do i run a method after a delay?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a question regarding calling methods after a certain amount of delay.

I want to call a Java method `exampleFunction()` after a delay of about 10 seconds. I have looked for solutions online and have come across the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor()`. So I have used this, but the thing is, once the function runs after 10 seconds, it doesn't exit from the thread. Is there any way I can exit from the thread? Or can I run the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor()` on the current thread instead of creating a new thread?

```
class Test {
     ...
     exampleFunction();
     ...

     public void exampleFunction() {
         ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
         exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 ...do something here...
             }
         }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }

}
```

So is there any way I can exit this thread after exampleFunction runs after a delay of 10 seconds? Or can I have the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` use the current thread instead of creating a new one?

Or is there another way I can approach this problem? I want to be able to run `exampleFunction()` after 10 seconds on the current thread, instead of creating a new thread.

Edit: I think it may not be a thread issue. I'm still trying to figure out the problem is. Thanks everyone for your suggestions and advice.

EDIT: Can I pass an argument to exampleFunction() and then use it inside public void run()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a method after a delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay)

Comment: When you say it doesn't exit from the thread do you mean that the pool thread stays running?  I assume the `run()` method completes, right?

Comment: Yes. That i think that is what the problem is. The pool thread remains running. The run() method does complete, but the thread continues to run.

Comment: @Aubin, i have tried the solutions in the link you specified. But none of them seemed to work.

Comment: The pool thread will be shutdown if you call `exec.shutdown();`.  Something else is going on.  Maybe do a thread dump using kill -QUIT to see what threads are running?  If you still see the `run()` method executing then it is blocked on something.

Comment: What is wrong with `Thread.sleep()`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem may be that you are not [shutting down the executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown%28%29) after your submit the job to it.

```
exec.schedule(...);
exec.shutdown();
```

The jobs that have been submitted will continue to run but you have to shutdown the service after you've submitted the last job to it.

Comment: I have tried exec.shutdown() as well. But the control still isn't going back to the first thread and remains with the thread created by the ScheduledPoolThreadExecutor.

Comment: What do you mean by the "control"?  Has the `run()` method finished or is it blocked doing UI operations or something?

Comment: The UI freezes after the exampleFunction() runs. So i was under the impression that execution is still in the ScheduledPoolThreadExecutor thread and doesn't go back to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Based on all the comments and confusion, any answer is just a guess.

What I think you want:

- The UI thread to invoke `exampleFunction`
- 'exampleFunction` to schedule a task for 10 seconds later and return immediately
- In 10 seconds time, to have the `run` method be invoked on the UI thread

In Swing, this is done by using [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

ExampleFunction would look like this:

```
 public void exampleFunction() {
     new Thread() {
         public void run() {
             TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10); //Will need a try/catch
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     ...do something here...
                 }
             });
         }
     }.start();
 }
```

*Note:* `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` could also be used.
*Note 2:* Although not usually advised, a simple Thread here is simpler than making a new Thread pool.

Comment: I'll try this. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I didn't do it right. Let me try again. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep` can be used if merely wishing to making the current thread *block*. If you do use a pooled executor, make sure to use it as a *pooled* executor - not one per (new) thread. To "exit" from a thread, just let execution run out of `run`. If using Swing, use the EDT.

Comment: How do i make sure i am using it as a pooled executor? Do i have to do something different from the code above? I do not wish to block the current thread. I want the current thread to execute normally, and then i want to run exampleFunction() on the current thread after 10 seconds.