# Timer between two event

Tags: android, timer, onclick

I want to use timer between to event , For ex: The user must be wait for 30s between clicked on button , How I can Do that ?!

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the button should only be clickable once every 30 seconds? In that case I would do something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    long time = System.System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(time >= lastClickTime + (30 * 1000) || lastClickTime == 0){
        lastClickTime = time;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate `Thread` and `postDelayed`

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay) shows how to do that as well as several other options

You would disable the `Button` in your `onClick()` then re-enable it in your `run()` function

[Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

[TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

A [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) would be another way. You would just re-enable the `Button` in `onFinish()`

You can look at these and see which will work best for your particular situation

Those are some of the ways that you could accomplish this. However, if you tell us your end game here we may be able to help you find a better way. You don't want the user to not be able to do ANYTHING for 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Handler's postDelayed method like this:

```
Button b; // instance variable


// now in onCreate


b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);     

final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        OuterClass.this.b.setEnabled(true);
    }

}, 30000); // 30 seconds = 30000 ms


b.setEnabled(false);


b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {           
        // do whatever you have to do
    }

});
```