# Enable No option after few seconds

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android application. There is a scenario that when user click on a button he is pop-up a dialog box (he can choose Yes or No) with a Google AdSense loaded in to it. My problem is the user can click on the No option before the ad is loaded to the dialog box. Hence I want to disable the No option for 5 seconds (hope add is loaded within that time frame) and enable it.

Here I have attached my code that loads AdSense. Could someone kindly direct me for correct path.

```
public static void dialogBoxAdsen(final String message,String positive,String negative,final Context context, final Context mContext, final String type){

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                // Do the yes work
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                // Do the No work
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_view, null);
    WebView webView        = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(TokeUtil.ADDSEN_URL);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setView(view).setPositiveButton(positive, dialogClickListener)      
        .setNegativeButton(negative, dialogClickListener).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this question:  [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay)

In particular look for the answer that uses a handler and has the most votes.