# Toast after seconds set by timepicker when screen off android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-timepicker, screen-off

i can detect when the screen turns off in this way:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Screen off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Screen on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}, intentFilter);
```

I need do the same thing, but the `Toast` will have to appears after a certain seconds that i can set through a `timePicker`. So every time the screen turns off, if i set 10 seconds, after 10 seconds i will get a toast. How can i do it? Do i need a service?
Manually i can do something like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

             // here the code
        }
}, 30 * 1000);
```

But if i could set the seconds with a time picker will be better. Thanks

Comment: You mean a Toast on a turned off screen?

Comment: Yes or a log.. it's the same.. I only need set a certain seconds time and after the screen off starts the timer and after the time setted it fires the toast or log. Understand now?

Comment: @End.Game  how u do this ???

Comment: @Erum in which sense?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a timer is fine, but a Toast on a powered off screen... you understand it will never appear, right?

If you want to apply a delay, prefer [Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() over Handler.postDelayed()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072338/603270).

Should definitely work.
Now you want the user to input the delay.

Just use a [TimePicker dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html), and set the delay in its callback.

Comment: Ok assuming use a log, so i can see it in the logcat. The example set the timer using the code.. like my example.. What exactly i need it's the possibility to set the timer with a picker. I mean, the user can set the timer manually. Right?