# How to trigger a method 200ms after an event is called?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I want to trigger a method 200ms after the onTouchUp event in android is called. I don't want to stop the current thread and I want to access the global variables in the method. I am also getting accelerometer data continuously so I don't want to stop or delay that. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a method after a delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay)

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is android, that is iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something to run a `Runnable` after a specified delay, such as [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

```
Runnable r = /* your runnable task */;
ScheduledExecutorService exec = /* your instance */;
exec.schedule(r, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a delay on a handler.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               methodToExecute(); 
            }
        }, 220)
```