# Call function with timeout

Tags: java, android

i have a function

```
protected void updateLogs()
```

in my activity (MainActivity).

I need to call this function with delay. I cann't use this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166354/3883330 because i can't call function from other class, because it's not static function. Code with error:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.updateLogs();
                }
            }, 100);
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: When you want to call a certain method from your MainActivity from another class. You should create an Interface in order to do that.

Comment: @Carnal i need to call it from MainActivity class

Comment: So, call it directly from your MainActivity. What's the problem?

Comment: @Carnal how i can call class method with timeout from this class?

Comment: What class? Could you be more specific?

Comment: just call updateLogs() or MainActivity.this.updateLogs()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateLogs();
    }
}, 100);
```

If it doesn't, declare a `final` object containing `this`:

```
final MainActivity main = this; // Just need to make it final
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        main.updateLogs();
    }
}, 100);
```

As [Carnal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718764/carnal) pointed out, it would be cleaner to declare an interface making the method to call public, however since you're calling it from an inner class, I think it's OK that way.