# Delaying false login attempts button by 10 seconds in Android then enable again?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code, It is for a login application which redirects to a website. I cannot find specific help online to disable the login_btn for a certain time period and then enable again with the attempts_remaining back to the initial 3. Any help much appreciated

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText username;
EditText password;
TextView attempt_count;
Button login_btn;
int attempts_remaining = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    attempt_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_attempts_count);
    login_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);



    login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("password")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent website = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.co.uk"));
               startActivity(website);


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                attempt_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                attempt_count.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                attempts_remaining--;
                attempt_count.setText(Integer.toString(attempts_remaining));


                if (attempts_remaining == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    login_btn.setEnabled(false);


                }
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple piece of code below your disable code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            login_btn.setEnabled(true);
            attempts_remaining = 3;
        }
    },10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android), you could try the following:

```
            if (attempts_remaining == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                login_btn.setEnabled(false);
                login_btn.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                      login_btn.setEnabled(true);
                      attempts_remaining = 3;
                   }
                }, 10 * 1000); // 10 seconds
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

what you need is a handler,
From Android's developers page https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

**There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own**

change your onClick method to this

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("password")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent website = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.co.uk"));
           startActivity(website);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            attempt_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            attempt_count.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            attempts_remaining--;
            attempt_count.setText(Integer.toString(attempts_remaining));


            if (attempts_remaining == 0) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                login_btn.setEnabled(false);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override //depending on if you are inheriting from a super class
    public void run() 
    {
        login_btn.setEnabled(true);
    }
}, 10000    // time in milliseconds, 10000ms = 10s
);
            }
        }

    }
});

 }
}
```

You might have to make some adjustments to fit you code, let me know how that went.