# How to set a delay for setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, delay

The below code is for ImageButton to change its image on every click. I have created a loop to change its position, but it changed so fast.

So I need a delay function. I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android), but it did not work for me.

> It says "Handler is abstract and cannot be instantiated"

The code:

```
public void ShapeSelectingInGame() {

    ShapeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ShapeButton = (ImageButton) v;
            selectShape = rand.nextInt(4);
            ShapeSaying = rand.nextInt(8);
            ColorOfShape = rand.nextInt(10);
            shapeID = "shape_" + selectShape + ShapeSaying + ColorOfShape;
            resID = getResources().getIdentifier(shapeID, "drawable", "com.example.asgames.hitit");
            ShapeButton.setImageResource(resID);
            HitTypeString.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 10; i < 10000; i += 100)
    {
        ShapeButton.setX(i);
    }
    ShapeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: see my answer you import wrong handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use handler.postDelay

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // your code here
}
}, 1000);
```

where 1000 means 1 second

Comment: it says "Handler is abstract and cannot be instantiated"

Comment: that should not come, make sure that you are importing android.os.Handler;

Answer (score 1):

Try this and pass milliseconds as the parameter:

```
wait(20000);
```

20000 means you are waiting for 20 seconds where 20000 are milliseconds.

Comment: it says "Unhandled excpetion: java.lang.InterruptedExcpetion"

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried this solution but did not work for me it says "Handler
>   is abstract and cannot be instantiated"

You have **imported wrong Handler** which is `ava.util.logging.Handler`

You should import following

> import android.os.Handler;

Answer (score 1):

```
   private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ShapeButton = (ImageButton) v;
            selectShape = rand.nextInt(4);
            ShapeSaying = rand.nextInt(8);
            ColorOfShape = rand.nextInt(10);
            shapeID = "shape_" + selectShape + ShapeSaying + ColorOfShape;
            resID = getResources().getIdentifier(shapeID, "drawable", "com.example.asgames.hitit");
            ShapeButton.setImageResource(resID);
            HitTypeString.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private static final int DELAY = 3000;
    public void ShapeSelectingInGame() {
        ShapeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, DELAY);
            }
        });

        for (int i=10; i<10000;i+=100)
        {
            ShapeButton.setX(i);
        }
        ShapeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


 }
```

It seems you have imported a wrong Handler class

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
```

Change it to

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

Comment: I corrected that but the object v is not declared anymore and the Image button never appeared

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code;

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

  // your code

 }
                }, 3000); // milisecond
```