# When the splash screen of my Android application opens the application crashes

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

Initially, the first version of my app worked fine.
Later, after changing to the sidebar drawer application template, it does not function properly, crashing the application (due to the splash screen).
What could be the issue?

This is the code for the SpashScreen.java file:

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    Thread myThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    myThread.start();
}
```

}

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/example"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/example"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post error log here

Comment: try using `SplashScreen.this` in place of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @AkhileshPatil Unfortunately no error appears, it compiles and then loads the splash screen for the time I have selected and then it crashes, showing the message "Unfotunately, the app has stopped"

Comment: you cannot start activity or do any UI work from worker thread so start your activity by adding `runonui` or `handler`

Comment: @AkhileshPatil thanks, but where exactly should I place "runonui"?

Comment: try my below answer use handler

Comment: add the logcat ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

Try this might help

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Exactly where should I write this? Thanks

Comment: Inside you onCreate method

Answer (score -1):

Try to use :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 3000);
```

This code don't create new Thread, 
P.S. Android cannot start activity from another Thread (only form UI)

Answer (score -1):

`startActivity()` need to be run in `main thread`. Using `postDelay()` of `Hanlder` class

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: so I should put this fragment of code in my MainActivity?

Comment: In your onCreate method.  Read this for understanding how to work with process and thead:https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html?hl=vi

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I put the code in the onCreate method but now it crashes before even showing the splash screen, thank you anyway

Comment: I don't know. I am going to study and understand better how threads work so I can find a soloution. The weird thing for me is that the code I initially wrote worked just fine for the empty activity project, but doesn't work for the drawer side bar project, which has the same code basically...

Comment: Both are activities. Not make sense

Answer (score -1):

using handler can solve this do below code it will work for you

```
  handler.postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(youractivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
                }
            }, 3000);
```