# Using sleep to pause a method for a second

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a simon says game so to let the user know which buttons to hit I decided I wanted to do something like upon a button click change background wait a second then change it back it doesn't work right though the button waits 1 second to click but the drawable doesn't change

What I have looks something like this

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);

try {
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);           
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
```

Comment: Look here at handler : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166354/940834 . Put your code inside the handler, that sets it back. with delay in milliseconds

Comment: Thank you the handler did the trick

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using `Handler`. In my example, I set a 5sec delay after which I change the background color via `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);`.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
      }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try CountDownTimer.

```
// You can change millisInFuture and countDownInterval according to your need.
long millisInFuture = 5000;
long countDownInterval = 1000;

new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
     @Override
     public void onTick(long l) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onFinish() {
         // Change your background color here
         view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
     }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use  `new Handler()`try something below like this.

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
      }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the view background in runOnUiThread and invalidating the view.

Comment: This should be a comment...post some code snippet useful to OP