# Stopping Android video after certain amount of time

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

I would like to play a video with a `VideoView` in fullscreen mode in Android 5.1. Moreover, I would like to stop the video (and changing the activity) after a certain amount of time (let's say 5min). How can I achieve that? My layout is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
   android:paddingLeft="2px"
   android:paddingRight="2px"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:paddingTop="2px"
   android:paddingBottom="2px"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

      <VideoView 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:id="@+id/VideoView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the following code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

        videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/test.mp4");

        videoView.start();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a "MediaPlayer" and then make a "Runnable" to stop the video at 5m. Then with a handler you call your Runnable with ".postDelayed) method like this:

```
public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity {

        MediaPlayer mp;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, "video");  
            mp.start();

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(stopPlayerTask, 500000);
        }

        Runnable stopPlayerTask = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mp.pause();
            }};
}
```

You need to adapt this example ;)