# Delay program by 10 sec by pausing execution

Tags: android

I want to pause my program for 10 sec. I don't want sleep code. After pausing for 10 sec I want to run my further code.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166354/7874047

Comment: If you want to wait for the onset of an event, then you better use CallBack, Listener or interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);
```

blatantly copied and pasted from here [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android)

Comment: this doesn't stop the execution.

Comment: Yes it won't stop the NEXT LINE OF CODE, which means you need to wrap your next lines of code in a method (or in the `run()` block)

Answer (score 0):

```
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                 //your code will execute after 10 secs

                }},10000);
```

Comment: this doesn't stop the execution.