# System delay effects on all commands

Tags: java, android, timer

There is an annoying problem guys, take a look at this code:

```
   textView.setText("hi");
   SystemClock.sleep(5000);
   textView2.setText("hi");
```

When you run this code logically text view must show "hi" and 5 seconds later text view 2 show "hi".
But this doesn't happen and after 5 seconds both of them together show this word!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking the main application thread and preventing the UI from being updated. This is covered in any decent book on Android app development.

Replace your code with this:

```
textView.setText("hi");
textView2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
     textView2.setText("hi");
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This can fix my problem but i want to use delay in for loop and this kind of delay can not be use full.

Comment: @Mehrdad: There is nothing about `postDelayed()` that prevents it from being used for periodic UI updates within an activity or fragment. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Threads/PostDelayed) displays a `Toast` every five seconds, using `postDelayed()`.

Comment: yea it use for toast but if u can show an example with for loop :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sorry, you cannot do what you want with a `for` loop, other than calling `postDelayed()` on each pass of the `for` loop, with progressively longer delays... and I don't know how well that will work, particularly for lots of loop passes.