# How to pause the task before the next task?

Tags: java, android

Thread.sleep(10000) waits for 10 sec before execution of the program. 

I want the code that waits the next task for 10 sec when the first task is running.

How do I execute the code with delay without clearing the screen?

Comment: Use `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);
```

Original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166354/4064490

Comment: i think this starts the timer after the program is started. I want to start the timer in the middle of the program.

Comment: What do you mean "the middle" @ShresthaBibash?

Comment: middle means  the timing must start when i want but not at the beginning

Comment: @ShresthaBibash Put Handler on event f.e. onClickListener and run your code with some delay. 
P.S. Beginning means what? Start of app? Start of Activity?