# Wait funtion in a while cycle?

Tags: android, wait

Is there any way to do a wait() function, in my case, in Android Studio?

```
function example ()
{
    while () 
    {
        //do something 
        //wait (x seconds) then go back
    }
}
```

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android

Comment: @vm345 its a game, and I need to change life of a character for hits (pe. 80hp, 60hp, 20hp, dead)

Comment: You can use `handler` for this

Comment: call wait function outside of while statement it may work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve this way:

```
//in your method, use the Timer Schedule function:
new Timer().schedule(  
    new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO: do something here of your interest.
        }
    },
    2000
);
```

Here I have kept the delay for 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds). You may change that according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int interval = 3000;//milliseconds interval for delay
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {


            }

            private void finish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, interval);
```