# Updating a textView value every 3 secs

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, countdowntimer

I'm using `listItems` array which contains checkboxes every checked item is saved in `mUserItems` array I want to print every checked item separated in `mItemSeleced` textView for 3 seconds using a countdown timer then delete it and get the other item for 3 seconds and so on;
the problem is after 3 seconds I only get the last item checked

```java
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mUserItems.size(); i++) {
        final int j = i;
        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
            public void onFinish() {
                mItemSelected.setText("");
                mItemSelected.setText(listItems[mUserItems.get(j)]);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop will start all count downs at once (almost). You should  use recursion here. Also consider using Handler.postDelayed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android

Comment: ho do i use recursion here?

Comment: i tried to use it but it makes my app  stop woking

Comment: Did you see the message that causes crash? I believe it can be that you are updating UI not on the main Thread

Comment: I just replaced the for loop wirh a recursion loop in the main thread, i think it is a logical error but i don not know ehat is it

Answer (score 0):

If you use loop or recursion, try using

delay(3000);
after the updating statement (then loop continues)!