# App isn't responding after pressing play button

Tags: android

So I have created a very basic drum machine that should play snare sounds in a loop when I press play, only when the toggle buttons are on until I press stop. Here is the main code of the play() method :

```
   public void play() {

        playing = true; 
        while (playing) {
            if (button1.isChecked()) {
                sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                if (!playing) {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4)); 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (button2.isChecked()) {
                    sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                    if (!playing) {
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (button3.isChecked()) {
                        sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                        if (!playing) {
                            break;
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (button4.isChecked()) {
                            sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                            if (!playing) {
                                break;
                            }
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when i press play, the app stop responding, i can't even press the stop button and i only here 1 snare sound even if i toggle more than 1 button and it doesn't seem to loop either since i only hear it once. So i'd like to know if my play() method is wrong and how can i fix the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is all of your `Thread.sleep` calls.  Each one of those blocks the UI thread for that period of time, freezing your application.

You should instead use [`Handler.postDelayed`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166354/208273) to do this without blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I understand my mistake so i tried to use your advice but I still have the same problem as before even when using Handler.postDelayed. Here is how I did it :
`new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (button2.isChecked()) {
                        sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                    }
                }
                }, 1000);`
Am I doing it wrong?