# Kotlin enable swipe refresh after delay

Tags: android, kotlin

At some point in my code a swipe refresh layout is disabled. I use:

```
swipe_refresh_layout.isEnabled = false
```

Then I want to set a timer for it to be re-enabled after some seconds. I have tried the solutions given in this question. [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

What i am currently using is the code below and the log message appears but I can't refresh.

```
val r = Runnable {
    Log.d("Test", "Re-enable refresher..")
    swipe_refresh_layout.isEnabled = true
}
Handler().postDelayed(r, 1000)
```

Can someone help as to what I might be doing wrong. Thanks