# Handler post delayed method in countdown timer

Tags: java, android, countdown

I am making timer and I want to repeat it, for example, 6 times, but I don't know how to set delay and how to each time display me the countdown again on tv1. My code look like that. As you can see in code, I am using Handler method, but I don't know  know if it's correct.

```
tv1=findViewById(R.id.textView);
btn1=findViewById(R.id.button);
final int x=10000;

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        timr =new CountDownTimer(x,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tv1.setText(""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        
                    }
                })
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no Handler in this code.  Could you add the relevant section of the code?

Comment: Sorry I paste wrong code ;/. I edited my question

Comment: That's not valid Java.  It's missing at least one semicolon, and `postDelayed` has two parameters, not one.

Comment: So what I should to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android)

Comment: for what do you need the Handler? You already have the tick happening almost every second. You won't manage to get it exactly every second. And the two methods `onTick` and `onFinish` are called on the main thread. So I don't see why you need the Handler

Comment: if im not wrong, you want to repeat your timer but give it start delay after a timer is finished?

Answer (score 1):

In `onFinish` method add this code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        timr.start()
    } 
},your_delay)
```