# How to run a cancellable scheduled task in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timertask

The kotlin function `delay()` has this specification:

> - Delays coroutine for a given time **without blocking a thread** and
>   resumes it after a specified time.  * This suspending function is
>   **cancellable**.  * If the [Job] of the current coroutine is cancelled or
>   completed while this suspending function is waiting, this function  *
>   immediately resumes with [CancellationException].

I want to achieve exact functionality using Java. Basically, I need to run a function using some delay and this should be cancellable anytime by some given condition.

I've already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android) thread, but most of the answers aren't quite the right fit for my scenario.

Comment: Have you considered using RxJava?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
 // Create the scheduler
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = 
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    // Create the task to execute
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    };
    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture =
        scheduledExecutorService. schedule(r, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  
    // Cancel the task
    scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
```

when you cancel it an `InterruptedException` will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks Maksym for the snippet, but where do I put this, so that I'll be able to cancel this task from any function within an activity?

Comment: nvm, I put the declaration of scheduledFuture in MainActivity class, and then I'm able to access it anywhere in the activity. but one more thing I need to know if I haven't scheduled anything, and I call this cancel function, is there gonna be any problem?

Comment: I don't 100% understand the question. `schedule` function returns the `scheduledFuture`, so I don't see how you can call it without scheduling...
If you have it like so `ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;` and then somewhere else `scheduledFuture.cancel(false);` then you most likely getting NullPointerException.

P.S. please consider accepting the answer if it satisfies your question.

Comment: Yeah, I accepted the answer. Was only waiting for your response! Thank you so much!