# how do you make an alert dialog if not presses will do something else

Tags: java, android

I want to make a program that will show an alert dialog with a confirmation button on it if it pressed it will continue and if not pressed for like 30 seconds will do something else. So far I get the gist of it for making the alert dialog show but later on if not pressed that I'm still working on it

Comment: you can use handler for this when you open the alert dialog run your time if use click on it just cancel the handler or if user not click on it than performe the action you want after handler finished

Comment: i did consider using handler but so far i haven't got an example of it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android)

Comment: well the link you give me was used for another project of mine but this one kinda different

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Handler

class DelayHandler {
var handler: Handler? = null
var runable: Runnable? = null

init {
    handler = Handler()

}

fun startDealay(sec: Long, listner: () -> Unit) {

    runable = Runnable { listner.invoke() }
    handler?.postDelayed(runable!!, sec)
}

fun cancelHandler() {
    if (handler != null) {
        runable?.let { handler?.removeCallbacks(it) }
    }
}
}
```

after you just call this where you want a handeler

```
  private val delayHandler: DelayHandler? = DelayHandler()

     delayHandler?.cancelHandler() // call this for cancel the handler on button click
            
     delayHandler?.startDealay(30 * 1000) { // 30 *1000 for 30 sec
                // your action
            }
```

Comment: OP has the java tag, all your code is kotlin, that isn't useful unfortunately